# Drilldown menu на чистом JS как сделать?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, mobile

Как можно сделать menu drilldown на чистом JavaScript без jquery?

пример меню
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/mobile-side-navigation-zeynepjs/

и как сделать, чтобы функция drilldown работал только в мобильном версии?

```html
<ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li class="has-submenu">
                <a href="#" data-submenu="stores">Stores</a>

                <div id="stores" class="submenu">
                    <div class="submenu-header" data-submenu-close="stores">
                        <a href="#">Main Menu</a>
                    </div>

                    <label>Stores</label>

                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Istanbul</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Mardin</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Amed</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="has-submenu">
                    <a href="#" data-submenu="categories">Categories</a>

                    <div id="categories" class="submenu">
                        <div class="submenu-header" data-submenu-close="categories">
                            <a href="#">Main Menu</a>
                        </div>

                        <label>Categories</label>

                        <ul>
                            <li class="has-submenu">
                                <a href="#" data-submenu="electronics">Electronics</a>

                                <div id="electronics" class="submenu">
                                    <div class="submenu-header" data-submenu-close="electronics">
                                        <a href="#">Categories</a>
                                    </div>

                                    <label>Electronics</label>

                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Camera &amp; Photo</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Home Audio</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Tv &amp; Video</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Computers &amp; Accessories</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Car &amp; Vehicle Electronics</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Portable Audio &amp; Video</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Headphones</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Accessories &amp; Supplies</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Video Projectors</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Office Electronics</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Wearable Technology</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Service Plans</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Books</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Video Games</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Computers</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: 1. JQuery - это всего лишь набор функций. Любую запись на JQuery можно "перевести" на JS. В вашем вопросе не видно JQuery функций, поэтому не могу показать на примере. Например `$('#id'`)` заменяется на `document.getElementById('id')`. Думаю другие функции так же можно на чистом JS записать, может часть из них будут функциями строк на 20-30-50 но всё можно записать.

Comment: 2. Если пользователь мобилки "не махлюет", то проверяйте userAgent. В топе гугла на слова userAgent мобилка есть решения, например http://only-to-top.ru/blog/coding/2019-11-16-opredelit-mobilnoe-ustrojstvo-javascript.html

Comment: источник примера меню
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/mobile-side-navigation-zeynepjs/

искал подобнее меню на js, не нашел... чтоб поэтапно понят каждую функцию...

Comment: zeynepjs по сути на ванильном JS и написан https://github.com/hsynlms/zeynepjs/blob/master/dist/zeynep.js, jQuery там минимум. Такой скрипт полностью перевести на ваниль не является чем-то сложным. Если хотя бы частично знаете JS, можете погуглить нативные аналоги jQuery и поправить скрипт самостоятельно. Либо заказать на фрилансе например, думаю, там большинство фрилансеров справятся с этим.

Comment: это называется еще push menu, sliding menu, есть библиотеки [mmenujs.com](https://mmenujs.com/examples.html) например